# Regex not matching the string format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i am receiving data over serial port and i want to verify if the data format is right. the data format i am expecting is like this

number,number,number,number -> **1200,2500,6500,90**

i am using the regex like this

`Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[0-4095]\,[0-4095]\,[0-4095]\,[0-4095]$")`

using 4095 because the number range is between 0 and 4095. need help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parse the numbers to ints and compare the values that is far easier than to compare number ranges in Regex Lingo.

Comment: If you want to make the pattern shorter, use an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) comma but force it by use of a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`. I came up with [`^(?:(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|[1-9]\d?\d?|0),?\b){4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/N3aubB/2/)

Answer (score 5):

you could do it without the need to depend on regex with a simple LINQ expression and int.TryParse method:

```
  var sections = e.Split(',');
  sections.Count() == 4 && 
  sections.All(s => int.TryParse(s, out int i) && i >= 0 && i <= 4095);
```

Comment: After working through a two step process validating the format with Regex, then parsing the integers to check their values, I concluded this is the best answer. Regular expressions have their limits. This is a case where I don't think regex is the right answer.

Comment: agree, regex becomes hard to read pretty fast which overcome the conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
^(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|\d{1,3}),(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|\d{1,3}),(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|\d{1,3}),(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|\d{1,3})$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/QNRoU0/1/)

might work OK, if `000,000,000,000` would be valid, otherwise,

```
^(?:(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|\d),){3}(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|\d)$
```

might be an option too.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/YD5YVI/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?:(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|\d),){3}(?:40\d[0-5]|[1-3]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|\d)$";
        string input = @"1200,2500,6500,90
            1200,2500,6500,90
            1200,2500,4095,90
            0,0,0,0
            999,1,0,99
            000,000,000,000
            4095,4095,4095,4095

            ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/r7xXFY/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/r7xXFY/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

We cannot do range on numbers like that. You may use this regex for your use case:

`^(([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|0[0-9][0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9]|3[0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-9][0-5]),){3}([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|0[0-9][0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9]|3[0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-9][0-5])$`

Edited:

`^(([0-9]{1,3}|0[0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{3}|2[0-9]{3}|3[0-9]{3}|40[0-9][0-5]),){3}([0-9]{1,3}|0[0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{3}|2[0-9]{3}|3[0-9]{3}|40[0-9][0-5])$`

Or,

`^(?:(?:\d{1,3}|[0-3]\d{3}|40\d[0-5]),){3}(?:\d{1,3}|[0-3]\d{3}|40\d[0-5])$`

I guess you now understand the idea. To check if a number lies between 0-4095,

- The number can be single digit 0-9
- It can be double digit [0-9][0-9]
- It can be any triple digit number [0-9][0-9][0-9]
- But, for a 4 digit number, we must ignore all numbers which are
  greater than 4095,

  That is why the query needs to be longer than usual.
- 1[0-9][0-9][0-9] covers all 4 digit numbers starting from 1.

...

- 40[0-9][0-5] covers all numbers between 4000 and 4095